# Core Location Not Finding Current Location

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

Current location is not being found on initial load or resume after multi-tasking. This is what I have:

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate, BEMSimpleLineGraphDelegate>
```

ViewController.m

```
@interface ViewController (){
 CLLocationManager *locationManager;
CLLocation *location;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
int timeofday;
NSString *cityName;
NSMutableArray *ArrayOfValues;
}
@end
```

Further down:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateLabels) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];

// set up coordinates for current location
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = (id)self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

location = [locationManager location];

}
```

Then my update labels method (which has other code that updates my view below this):

```
- (void)updateLabels
{

CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation = [location coordinate];

if (currentLocation.latitude) {
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                       if (error){
                           NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                           return;
                       }
                       CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                       cityName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ is currently",placemark.locality];
                   }];
    [self updateLabels];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Could not find the location.");
}


}
```

And here are the 2 delegate methods for cclocationmanager:

```
#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];
}



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
//NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;





        [self updateLabels];


    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                       if (error){
                           NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                           return;
                       }
                      // CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

                   }];




}
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` from `viewDidLoad` and into `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: Does your app have permeation to use your location? Check location privacy setting in the Settings app..

Comment: Yes it does on my test device and also in the simulator (with a custom location selected before opening and verified when running the app that the location is still selected).

Comment: I had the same problem i just copied code in `viewwillAppear` and problem was solved..

Answer (score 0):

Your call to updateLabels is using the value set in the member variable location. However your didUpdateToLocation method is not setting this value.

Put some breakpoints in your code and see where it triggers.

Note, for a weather application  you do not need kCLLocationAccuracyBest, that takes way more time than coarser settings. You'll get your answer much quicker.

Comment: Shouldn't I only need to get one location in order to populate my labels? I am using the location to make an API request to a weather API. I don't need to continuously update. I figured this was better for battery performance.

Comment: I'd say your app should work once. You question talk about resuming, when the app entered the foreground. Does it work even once?

Comment: ahhh, that's very different, let me look again.

Comment: Which location accuracy would you suggest? I would like to be as specific as possible, since the API will provide data down to the street level.

Comment: Experiment and see what works for you. I don't know of any weather service that is free and works down to the street level. Think about it, do you care if the weather is different on the street you are on versus the next street over? Probably not.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the call to stopUpdatingLocation. Also un-comment the log statement in didUpdateToLocation.

Be aware that the method `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` is deprecated in iOS 6. It might not even be called in iOS 7. You should be using `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:' instead.

Comment: I removed the call to stopUpdatingLocation and now I just get repeated logs of 'Could not find location.'

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `location`, which I assume is a class level iVar, in `ViewDidLoad`.

```
location = [locationManager location];
```

I expect that the location manager at that point has no location.

Then, in the delegate call, you are updating a method level iVar :

```
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
```

This variable is never used, that I can see. Your `updateLabels` call once again refers to `location` which has never been updated.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation = [location coordinate];
```

Change the delegate to:

```
location = newLocation;
```

As @Duncan C stated, the delegate method you are using is deprecated, you should really be using `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` in which case you would use:

```
location = [locations lastObject];
```